# Jmeter-SSH SFTP -Permission denied for download file

Tags: jmeter

I am using SSH SFTP sampler to connect to SFTP. I need to download the files from SFTP. i have selected Action-"Get" and source path s SFTP file path location and destination is local folder path. I am getting error Permission denied. The same works if i try Action "ls"

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the user account you're using for establishing SFTP session doesn't have [read permission](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions) therefore you cannot read file contents hence not able to copy it.

Make sure that the user has read permissions and if this is not the case - provide the permission using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command like:

```
chmod +r your_file
```

[image: Jmeter File Permissions SSH SFTP]

Check out [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) article for more information.

---

If you still experience problems - update your question to show [SSH SFTP](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp) sampler configuration.